# Creating file python

Tags: python, user-interface, directory, tuples

I've got a little problem with creating file in python. I'd like to create it on a desktop and name it. Than my program should create anoter folder in it and take a name from user, but when I do something like this:

```
def folder(self):
    home = os.sep.join((os.path.expanduser('~'),'Pulpit'))
    if not os.path.exists(home):
        home = os.path.join((os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop'))
    opto = home + '\OptoMaQ'
    self.directory = opto
    nam = str(self.nmget.get())
    mypath = opto + '\%s'  %nam
    if not os.path.exists(opto):
        os.makedirs(opto)
        if len(nam) == 0:
            self.fold.config(text = 'This name is incorrect',background = 'red')
        else:   
            if not os.path.exists(mypath):
                os.makedirs(mypath)
                self.fold.config(text = 'Folder was created',background = 'green')
            else:
                self.fold.config(text = 'This name is taken',background = 'red')
    else:
        if len(nam) == 0:
            self.fold.config(text = 'This name is incorrect',background = 'red')
        else:   
            if not os.path.exists(mypath):
                os.makedirs(mypath)
                self.fold.config(text = 'Folder was created',background = 'green')
            else:
                self.fold.config(text = 'This name is taken',background = 'red')
```

It's for GUI programing of course. When i run it, there is an error: " opto = home + '\OptoMaQ' TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple". The funny thing is that it worked for me a few days ago and now i doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
if not os.path.exists(home):
    home = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')
opto = home + r'\OptoMaQ'
```

`os.path.join` does not take tuple as an argument, `os.sep.join` does.

Comment: But it still doesn't work. After removing those "(" and adding "r" my code looks exacly as Yours up here but there is an error that  "join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)"